# Vertx: Why is there no clustered verticle?

Tags: java, networking, vert.x

im messing around with my two verticles , which I want to start in clustered Mode.

Here are the start-Methods of my two verticles:

First Verticle:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();

    options.setClustered(true);
    options.setClusterManager(new HazelcastClusterManager());

    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
        Vertx vertx = res.result();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new WalzenSchnittBlMock());

    });

}
```

Second Verticle:

```
public void start() {
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();

    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
        vertx = res.result();
        vertx.deployVerticle(serviceVerticle, this::completeRegister);
    });
}
```

Thhis two verticles reside on different machines, but they do not "see" each other, although there are in clustered mode....is there any problem..have i missed something?

Comment: Did you enable Hezelcast logging? I would start from there: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_enabling_logging

Comment: I agree about enabling logging. You might also check firewall rules. Are both machines on the same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I have two machines and each of them have four networkcards - and vertx seems to choose the wrong one. So I am forced to set the Ip-adress which vertx should use. The result looks like that where the Ipadress is an argument of the jar-file :

```
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();

    Config config = new Config();
    NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();

    networkConfig.getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface(args[0]);
    options.setClusterManager(new HazelcastClusterManager(config));
    options.setClustered(true);
    options.setClusterHost(args[0]);

    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
        Vertx vertx = res.result();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new Receiver());

    });
```